# Joining 3 tables on a date criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with this.

Tbl: WarehouseInventory

```
Date       | DelRec | ProductId | Quantity
2015-09-10 | 110    | 1         | 100
2015-09-12 | 111    | 1         | 100
2015-09-12 | 111    | 2         | 200
2015-09-12 | 111    | 3         | 300
```

Tbl: Withdrawals

```
Date       | ID     | ProductId | Quantity | CustomerId
2015-09-11 | 1      | 1         | 400      | 2
2015-09-12 | 1      | 1         | 100      | 1
2015-09-12 | 2      | 2         | 200      | 1
2015-09-12 | 3      | 3         | 300      | 1
```

Tbl: Customers

```
Customer Id     | Name 
1               | Somebody
2               | Someone
```

The output should be like this

```
DelRec | Date Added | ProductId | Stocked | Withdrawn | Customer 
  110  | 2015-09-10 | 1         | 100     | 0         | NULL
  0    | 2015-09-11 | 1         | 0       | 400       | Someone
  111  | 2015-09-12 | 1         | 100     | 100       | Somebody
  111  | 2015-09-12 | 2         | 200     | 200       | Somebody
  111  | 2015-09-12 | 3         | 300     | 300       | Somebody
```

This is what I have come up so far and it's giving me a wrong output

```
select wi.DateAdded as 'Date Added', max(wi.DeliveryReceipt) as 'Delivery Receipt', wi.ProductId as 'Product',
     max(isnull(wi.Quantity, 0)) as 'Stocked', max(isnull(w.Quantity, 0)) as 'Withdrawn', e.Customers as 'Customer'
     from WarehouseInventory wi 
     cross join Withdrawals w 
     cross join Customer e 
     group by wi.DateAdded, wi.ProductId, e.Customers, wi.DeliveryReceipt, w.ProductId
```

Basically, I need to join the two tables on the date and product and if there is a null value in one of the tables, just make it 0. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few inconsistencies between your example table and your query, but here's the basic gist:

- You want to FULL OUTER JOIN your Warehouse delivery (A) and Withdrawal (B) tables on both product and date
- Make sure you coalesce(A, B) for both date and product
- Sum the quantities from each table, then coalesce outside each aggregate to get zeros (since one column can be all nulls).

Here:

```
select 
  coalesce(wi.DateAdded, w.date) as 'Date Added', 
  max(wi.DeliveryReceipt) as 'Delivery Receipt', 
  coalesce(wi.ProductId, w.productId) as 'Product',
  coalesce(sum(wi.Quantity), 0) as 'Stocked', 
  coalesce(sum(w.Quantity), 0) as 'Withdrawn', 
  e.name as 'Customer'
from WarehouseInventory wi 
  full outer join Withdrawals w on w.date = wi.dateadded and w.productId = wi.productId
  left join Customer e on e.customerId = w.customerId 
group by 
  coalesce(wi.DateAdded, w.date), 
  coalesce(wi.ProductId, w.productId), 
  e.name
```

Comment: Your solution works! Thank you! I just copied your solution, changed some field names and it gave me the right output except for one; All the customer is NULL and I can't get it to work. I have to study on this new key word for me... "COALESCE". Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DelRec, 
       COALESCE(wi.[Date], wd.[Date]) AS Date_Added,
       COALESCE(wi.ProductId, wd.ProductId) AS ProductId,
       COALESCE(wi.Quantity, 0) AS Stocked,
       COALESCE(wd.Quantity, 0) AS Withdrawn,
       c.Name AS Customer
FROM WarehouseInventory AS wi
FULL OUTER JOIN Withdrawals AS wd 
ON wi.[Date] = wd.[Date] AND wi.ProductId = wd.ProductId
LEFT JOIN Customers AS c ON c.[Customer Id] = wd.CustomerId 
ORDER BY Date_Added
```

Comment: i've just upvoted your answer but it's missinng the grouping and MAX evaluation (apart the misleading title and the lacking formulation of the question)

Comment: @rfb I've got the impression that there is a single row per `Date`, `ProductId`. If this is the case then grouping is not necessary. I believe the OP tried to use grouping because of the many redundant rows produced by the `CROSS JOIN` he is using. But let us know what the OP really wants.

Comment: I repeat tha OP has given a bad formulation, and you're definetely right about redundancy in `CROSS JOIN`. But generally arguing and not basing on sample data, nothing says that `WarehouseInventory` can't have `Date` and `ProductId` repeated in different rows (same `Date` and `ProductId` and different `DelRec`).
Consider also that the output is showing a stock.